# Objective c iPhone redirect to error page for uncaught exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, exception, error-handling

I have a class I want to redirect user to Error page if theres been an: uncaught exception , a caught exception or a custom exception. I also want to flick off an error email. (so that I'm notified).

I can't access the current View Controller within this class (in the case of an uncaught exception). Because its triggered with the delegate listener `onUncaughtException(NSException* exception)`.

How can I access the current view controller, or failing that, modally redirect user to an Error view controller?

```
#import "ErrorHelper.h"
#import "ErrorViewController.h"
#import "Global.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation ErrorHelper


+(void) handleUncaughtError:(NSException*) exception
{
    NSLog(@"Uncaught exception occurred!");
    
    [self sendErrorEmailIfAppropriate:exception :nil];
    [self redirectToErrorPage];
}

+(void) handleCaughtError:(NSException*) exception
{
    NSLog(@"Error caught!!");
    
    [self sendErrorEmailIfAppropriate:exception :nil];
    [self redirectToErrorPage];
}

+(void) handleCaughtCustomError:(NSString*) ref :(NSString*) details
{
    NSLog(@"Custom error caught!!");
    //can do conditional branching on @ref, to do appropriate action.
    
    [self sendErrorEmailIfAppropriate:nil :details];
    [self redirectToErrorPage];
    
    
}

+(void) sendErrorEmailIfAppropriate:(NSException*) exception :(NSString*)details
{
    if([[Global get] isInTestMode] || [[Global get] isInLiveMode]) {
        bool isCustomException = details != nil;
        
    }
}

+(void) redirectToErrorPage
{
    /*Try redirect user to error page
    E.G:
     -There's been an error, our App Dev team will try and resolve the issue for you
     -Regards -Dev team
     
    */
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    
}
```

@end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this from: [exception_handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787254/showing-an-alert-in-an-iphone-top-level-exception-handler) Its working! Just write your email sending code instead of the alert view.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{        
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&exceptionHandler);

    return YES;
}

BOOL exceptionAlertDismissed = FALSE;
void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Committed Suicide"
        message:@"Oh dear, that wasn't supposed to happen. You will have to restart the application... sorry!"
        delegate:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"That's ok!", @"Erm, bye...", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    while (exceptionAlertDismissed == FALSE)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    exceptionAlertDismissed = TRUE;
}
```

In interface,

```
@interface ...appDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
...
void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception);
```

Comment: it's way too late to safely recover and resume using the approach in this answer. docs for `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`: *"Sets the top-level error-handling function where you can perform last-minute logging before the program terminates."*. logging is one thing. continuing or recreating the main thread's run loop and presenting alerts -- not safe.

Comment: @justin you are right but as far as catching exceptions and sending an email synchronously is concerned, I think this will work. I'm not sure how his email sending method works. But I think it must be called synchronously. Otherwise it may crash before the email being sent.

Comment: personally, i would just write the info to a file and exit. then try to transmit it or present an error when relaunched, if the file exists.

Comment: @justin I would simply go for the app crash reports. Thats a bit more technical though, but it works in most cases ;). And as you may know that all app crashes are synced with iTunes whenever users connect their devices to PC/Mac. Apple send these reports to developers.

Comment: yeah, i would too :) the OP wants a different (or supplemental) behavior -- beyond what the crash report provides.

Answer (score 4):

You should be under the assumption that Cocoa exceptions are non-recoverable. Don't throw them, don't add them to your program. (Using exceptions in C++ is fine, although mixing C++ and ObjC can be unsafe in this regard because ObjC is just not designed for this control flow or cleanup at unwind).

There are a few oddball ObjC APIs which throw, and you could recover from some of them. If possible, use an alternative which does not throw. If you **must** try/catch in this scenario, then you should *make your handler as local to the callsite as possible*. Assume an uncaught ObjC exception or one caught by a high level handler is unrecoverable.

Now, because your caught exception is local to the callsite, you can easily add the logic to propagate the error to a view controller or back into the event loop (e.g. an AlertView). Yes, you will likely have some error out parameters or return values to introduce in this case.

Email is a separate question.

Comment: Now I think I deserve the +50 bounty :p. Stackoverflow should make changes to the system so that when accepted answer changes, the bounty should also be transferred. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really wants to achive this you can try something like,

1 - Store your current screen object in a UIViewController object(Application level) in your  viewDidAppear method.

2 -This will give you the current screen where ever in the app.

(I have not tested this but i guess should work)

3 - Send Notification (bcoz now you have that current screen instance).

4 - Display your error page

Answer (score 1):

in the main.m class use -

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = -1;
@try {
    retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
@catch (NSException* exception) {
    NSLog(@"Uncaught exception: %@", exception.description);
    --Send email here or Open ur link or Wat ever action u'd like to do or Use the Error helper class of urs HERE--
}
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

The idea is that all the crashes due to any object will finally pass through the main.m class which the best place to see crashes in the entire App life cycle..

Comment: I tried this. I modified your code for the new ARC main.m. It crashes on the line 'UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));' and never gets to '@catch'

Comment: shall go inside @catch block, could u show the ARC code u did?

Comment: 'int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int retVal = -1;
    at_autoreleasepool {
        at_try {
            retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
        }
        at_catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Caught exception = %@", exception.description);
        }
        at_finally {
            NSLog(@"Do something!");
        }
        
        return retVal;
        
//          return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}'

Comment: turn off ARC for main.m file using this-> -fno-objc-arc compiler flag at Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources and use the code I gave..

Answer (score 1):

see [Showing an alert in an iPhone top-level exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787254/showing-an-alert-in-an-iphone-top-level-exception-handler) for info on how to install a global exception handler .. but as justin said, the exceptions should be treated as 'fatal' -- you can open a url/show a webview even

but dont try to resume normal operation afterwards