# Alternative to NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make a general error handler for an iPhone app that brings the user to a recovery screen whenever any general error is thrown in the application without putting a try/catch block around every single method in the application.

Using `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` doesn't work because the application terminates after the handler is run.

Is there any way to change this behavior, or use any other handler that will catch exceptions in general and not cause the application to exit afterward?

And please, no non-answers about whether it's a good or bad idea.

Comment: I am also following in the same way like keeping try catch blocks in every methods which seems not a gud idea. how u solved this /

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original poster has probably solved his problem by now. However, for anyone who comes across this  in the future...

Matt Gallagher wrote an excellent [post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html) on catching unhandled exceptions and signals a few months after this question was posted. I find it to be much more informative than the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128539/nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-not-catch-all-errors-on-iphone) referenced above by Scott.

In particular, Matt's post describes how to attempt a recovery (if appropriate) that allows your app to *keep running*, and even displays a UIAlertView with error information if you want (hint: it involves creating a new run loop).

Answer (score 2):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128539/nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-not-catch-all-errors-on-iphone). You can read more about the responder chain and catching the exceptions [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH201-SW1). The write up from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128539/nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-not-catch-all-errors-on-iphone) is really good and explains how to deal with what you are doing.