# How can I intercept fatal exceptions?

Tags: ios, ipad, exception

I want to integrate in my iPad application a way to monitor the user activity and especially the exceptions that occurred and triggered the application to stop, something like the bug report of Apple but for the mobile clients.

I tried to encapsulate the main action (`main.m`) between `@try` and `@catch` blocks, but the exception is not thrown until there, and I just can't add such blocks everywhere in my code. Neither the delegate method `applicationWillTerminate` is not called, the application is just brutally stopped without any notification.

Any ideas on this ?

Comment: The solution presented at < [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282364/how-do-you-implement-global-iphone-exception-handling) > resolved my situation. In the indicated response, only the **Approach1** and **Approach2** did worked for me. 

Can't understand why the above example similar to the one I've tried does not work, it should be the same as a unhandled exception handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me in `main.m`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool { 
        int retVal = 0;
        @try {
            retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
            [exception raise];
        }

        return retVal;    
    }
}
```

P.S.

Another tricky way : [EXC_BAD_ACCESS automatic handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315526/exc-bad-access-automatic-handling)

And example of [NSUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://creativeinaustria.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/crash-reporter-for-iphone-applications/)

Comment: Imagine the following scenarios: add 'nil' into a mutable array or try to access a non-exiting index in an array. This is not so unusual situations, might be a controller or element that in a some kind of situation it is invalid and not present, therefore the exception thrown will not be caught by the application not even instead of NSException a NSError is used. The application will just be stopped without any notification.

Comment: You're right, totally forgot about `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`

Comment: Is better than nothing in lack of a better solution.